# How to make font-size less for 2px than parent element?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have two `<span>`s. First is `font-size: 14px;` and I want to reduce `font-size` of child `<span>` for `2 px;`

```
<span>14px font <span>12px span</span></span>
```

How to do this **without** obvious setting `font-size: 12px;`? Is it possible with CSS? Or should I use jQuery?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/2GdZ9/), of course.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't mind using a feature with less than full support, I believe you could use CSS3's calc() For example:

`font-size: calc(100% - 2px);`

According to the spec the spaces around the operator are necessary. `calc(100%-2px)` may not work.

Unfortunately, **this doesn't work on a lot of older browsers** including IE8 and iOS Safari < 6. If you want to support them, a javascript solution like Quentin or Zeaklous came up with is your best bet.

**References:**

- http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/
- http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Answer (score 6):

<del>CSS has no features which allow the setting of a value plus or minus a number of length units.</del> @Yumecosmos points out that modern browsers support [calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

You could use relative units: `font-size: 85%`, but that wouldn't be `2px` except when the parent font size was `14px` (and even then it is approximate).

If you want to read the current value and then subtract 2px from it then you can [break out the JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sd2A/).

Comment: +1 - For relative units in CSS I would recommend **em** vs **%**, but this is an accurate answer to the question

Comment: +1 This is how I'd do it too. [Here, have a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GdZ9/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery/javascript to reduce the font size of children spans if they are there

```
$('span').each(function() { 
    if($(this).find('span')) {
        $(this).children('span').css({'font-size':'-=2px'});
    }
})
```

The advantage of this approach would be that all succeeding level of `span`s font size's are reduced by `2px` from their parent's value (if that's what you're looking for)

[**Demo of that here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2GdZ9/7/)

Answer (score -2):

For clarity, you may want to give your spans classes so you can target them more meaningfully.

CSS:

```
.normal-text {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.normal-text .small-text {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="normal-text">L<span class="small-text">arger first letter!</span></span>
```